# How Would I subset in sas most efficiently?

Tags: sas

I can subset by reading all the data in but that's the only way I am trying to subset while reading the data in.

Data: variables are `Id`, `group`, `diff`, `pre` and `post`.

```
2 Treatment +5 235 240 3 Treatment -2 212 210 6 Control -1 214 213

4 Control +4 199 203 7 Treatment -7 210 203 5 Control +8 222 230
```

This is what I tried to do:

```
data Tchol;
    infile '/home/u47436065/Data/TChol.dat';
    input Id Group :$9. @@;
    if Group = 'Control' then 
        input Diff Pre Post;
    else delete;
run;
```

I also did this but it's not the efficient way:

```
data Tchol;
    infile '/home/u47436065/Data/TChol.dat';
    input Id Group :$9. Diff Pre Post @@;
    if Group = 'Control';
run;
```

It worked great but not the right way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What makes you think it's not the 'right way'? The first section is what I would have recommended.

Comment: When `input`ing from a data file the only ways to subset the rows read are `IF` or the data set option `(WHERE=(...))` on the `DATA` data set name.  An `IF` **without** a THEN clause is known as a subsetting IF.

Comment: The first section doesn't work because it reads the first first two inputs, then since the group variable isn't control it reads the next two variables which is 5 and 235 when I want it to skip to the 3 if it isn't the right group. But if it does have the right input it reads it correctly and goes to the next line once all variables are read instead of continuing on the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading from a text file, so you need to read the whole file (or at least up to the point where you want to stop).  There is not really any efficiency to be gained by trying to skip reading some of the values along the way.  The amount of time spent converting the text into variable values is going to be trivial compared to the time spent reading the file off the disk.

So the efficiencies to be gained here is in code simplification.  Rather than complicate the code to read the values in two different places just read every variable at once.

And your attempt to short circuit reading the other values for an observation is going to cause you to read the values into the wrong variables.

```
NOTE: Invalid data for Id in line 1 26-34.
RULE:     ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+--
1         2 Treatment +5 235 240 3 Treatment -2 212 210 6 Control -1 214 213 66
Id=. Group=-2 Diff=. Pre=. Post=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=4
```

If you remove the DELETE statement and look at the resulting dataset you will see that more clearly.

```
Obs     Id    Group        Diff    Pre    Post

 1       2    Treatment      .       .       .
 2       5    235            .       .       .
 3     240    3              .       .       .
 4       .    -2             .       .       .
 5     212    210            .       .       .
 6       6    Control       -1     214     213
 7       4    Control        4     199     203
```

So the code you want should be closer to your second example:

```
data Tchol;
  infile mydat ;
  input Id Group :$9. Diff Pre Post @@ ;
  if Group = 'Control';
run;
```

Comment: Yes that's what I think I'm supposed do I was curious if there was a way to put the if statement  after group then take in the rest of the variables if it is the right group. This is just how the homework assignment wants it that's why.

Comment: You will need to show the actual question. There are some text files where it is important to base the input on the type of record being read. For example if one type of record has a different number of values than another type of record.  But the data you showed does not need that.